# Throttle ALTER TABLE disk utilization

Tags: mysql, database, indexing, alter-table

I'll start off with something from the MySQL [Online DDL Limitations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-create-index-limitations.html) page:

> There is no mechanism to pause an online DDL operation or to throttle I/O or CPU usage for an online DDL operation.

However, I'm still interested in solutions that I might have missed.

The situation: Indexes are getting larger and larger, and they're getting so large that there won't be enough memory for the queries that are used, causing disk I/O to skyrocket, and everything to descend into utter chaos. New composite indexes have been created that are smaller, but the problem is running the `ALTER TABLE` without breaking anything.

The facts are as follows:

1. It's an InnoDB table.
2. The table has no primary key or unique index.
3. No combination of columns is suited as a primary key or unique index.
4. The table has no foreign keys.
5. The table is partitioned per month (currently 50).
6. The table must accept writes at all times.
7. The newest 3-6 partitions must accept reads.
8. There is an `id` column, but this is not unique.
9. The table consists of approximately 2 billion rows.
10. The partition of the current month is the only one that receives writes.
11. Partitions are made 1 month in advance; there's always one empty partition.

The `SHOW CREATE TABLE` (I didn't include all partitions):

```
CREATE TABLE `my_wonky_table` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `login` varchar(127) DEFAULT NULL,
  `timestamp` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET ascii DEFAULT NULL,
  `val_1` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `val_2` varchar(127) DEFAULT NULL,
  `val_3` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `val_4` varchar(127) DEFAULT NULL,
  `val_5` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `my_wonky_table_id_idx` (`id`),
  KEY `my_wonky_table_timestamp_idx` (`timestamp`),
  KEY `my_wonky_table_val_1_idx` (`val_1`,`id`),
  KEY `my_wonky_table_val_2_idx` (`val_2`,`id`),
  KEY `my_wonky_table_val_4_idx` (`val_4`,`id`),
  KEY `my_wonky_table_val_5_idx` (`val_5`,`id`),
  KEY `my_wonky_table_ip_idx` (`ip`,`id`),
  KEY `my_wonky_table_login_idx` (`login`,`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
/*!50100 PARTITION BY RANGE (`id`)
(PARTITION pdefault VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE ENGINE = InnoDB) */
```

Regarding queries: It's always a `SELECT` on `id`, with everything else being used to filter.

What I would like to avoid:

- Turning off the database instance.
- Disk I/O of 100%

I've thought of using the `pt-online-schema-change` tool to throttle, but ran into the no primary key wall. A different solution would be to do this in code, effectively moving the triggers to the code base, and slowly copying over data using somewhat weird chunks (e.g. chunks of an hour's worth of data using a timestamp column) because there's no unique index.

Are there other solutions and/or tools available?

Comment: Do you have foreign keys for that table? Also, do you need to be able to read the whole data the whole time (and/or can you e.g. adjust your application to access different tables during maintainance), since you only specified that you have to be able to write at all times? Also, would the I/O for that specific table itself be a problem, or the I/O on the server in general (as it might slow down the rest of the server)

Comment: Good questions! I updated the list of facts. Also, the I/O pertains the entire server. Strange things start happening all over when disk utilization hits 100%.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; there is more info I need to see.  How many partitions?  What are the typical queries?  What `ALTERs` are you performing?  Meanwhile, more on partitioning:  https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/partition-maintenance/

Comment: Is it necessary to keep all this data in one table?

Comment: Added extra information. The `ALTER` is to specifically combine several indexes into fewer composite indexes, as they are always together. The data has to stay within this table, yes.

Comment: Mysql 5.7 handles alter commands better esp. for huge tables.. so as to have min. downtime

Comment: Are the writes localized to one partition?  Do you let any data get into the pdefault partition?  Are some of the partitions currently empty?  (That is have you pre-built future partitions?

Comment: @RickJames Updated the facts. The writes are localized to a single partition, yes. There's always an empty partition.

Comment: I think that this could be asked on http://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: We _really_ should investigate your slow queries.  Perhaps [_Summary tables_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables) would relieve the pressure.  They often speed things up 10-fold, and remove contention between reads and writes.

Comment: Can you specify what MySQL version/variant you're using? Regardless of how you slice it, even before the indices, your table represents ~1.3TiB of data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Create a `new` table similar to the `real` table, but with the revised indexes.  Include a `PRIMARY KEY` so that you won't be trapped again.  -- This is the `ALTER`, but not yet the "populate".
2. In the new table, use quarterly or annual partitions for old stuff; monthly for current and (later) future partitions.  -- This is to keep down the total number of partitions.  My Rule of Thumb is "no more than 50 partitions".  (Let me know if you have a problem with this plan.)
3. Write a script to slowly copy all the data from the *old* partitions into the `new` table.  My advice on [*chunking*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks) may be useful here.
4. Just before you are caught up, create a new partition.  But don't copy from it yet.  Stop the "copy" script at the end of the previous partition.
5. When caught up *except for this new partition*, stop writes.
6. Copy the last partition. -- Here's where step #4 pays off.
7. Atomic swap:  `RENAME TABLE real TO old, new TO real;`.  And turn write on again.

Writing all the scripts and practicing on another machines is strongly advised.  The practice can be on a small subset of the total, but it needs to have at least a few partitions.

Comment: My current solution was to use pt-online-schema-change with a lot of things turned off (chunk-size-limit 0, no drops, no-check-plan, no-swap-tables, and no triggers (I disabled them all)) and then do a diff over two 24 hours dumps after the swap to insert the difference after the ALTER. I quite like step 5 here, though! I wonder whether that would have been easier to fit in; something iffy we had, is the system that does writes to the table has a 24 hour retention queue. I can't just stop writes, though, unless you mean the copies? I want to try this out; similar to the percona tool, though.

Comment: Good luck.  Ah, I did not realize that one could turn off Triggers in pt-osc.  24hr -- the data is removed after 24 hours?  But you have months of data?

Comment: The "stop writes" also happens in pt-osc.  The trick is to make it so short that the writers are not really inconvenienced.  I don't know your situation, so I can't get into details there.  Hopefully the writers already can handle a brief network outage via retrying or something.

Comment: The pt-online-schema-change tool is ultimately a Perl script. I simply disabled triggers (and some extra stuff for the delete trigger). The 24 hours is the timeout for something to tell the application to not write an entry, if it receives a go-ahead, or the 24 hours are up, it's an `INSERT INTO`. Wasn't aware of the writes stopping in the pt-osc, thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

I present this as a separate Answer, since the innermost part is totally different.

As with my other answer, you need the `new` table with new indexes, plus a script to copy all the data over.  However, the meat is to simulate the Trigger in *your application*.

Fortunately, you have `id`, even though it is not the `PRIMARY KEY`.  And, even if it is not `UNIQUE`, it can be used (assuming you don't have thousands of rows with the same id -- if you do, we can talk further).

The "copy script" and the application talk to each other.

The copy script is in a long loop:

- `SELECT GET_LOCK('copy', 5), high_water_mark FROM tbl;`  -- (or some other timeout)
- Copy rows with `id BETWEEN high_water_mark AND high_water_mark + 999`.
- `UPDATE tbl SET high_water_mark = high_water_mark + 1000;`
- Pause briefly  (1 second?)
- Loop until no more `ids`

The application, when reading, continues to read from the old table.  But when writing, it does:

- `SELECT GET_LOCK('copy', 5), high_water_mark FROM tbl;`  -- (or some other timeout)
- If timed out, something needs fixing.
- Write to old table -- (hence, reads continue to work)
- If `id` <= `high_water_mark`, write to new table also.
- `SELECT RELEASE_LOCK('copy');`

Monitor the progress.  At some point, you will need to stop everything, copy the last few rows and do the `RENAME TABLE`.

I don't know *your* optimal values for timeouts, sleep, or chunk size.  But I don't think it is wise for chunk size to be bigger than 1K.

This technique has advantages for a variety of changes you might need to do in the future, so keep the guts in place.

Answer (score 1):

This is going to come down to what MySQL variant & version you are using, but if it's one thread per connection (my.cnf `thread_handling=one-thread-per-connection`, which might be default on your build), and you can put your `ALTER TABLE` workload in a new connection, then workload is a unique PID, and you can use `ionice`/`renice` on it.

I have somewhat of a crappy answer, but it's less invasive than the other options.

If you look at `ps -eLf |grep mysql` you can see the threads/lightweight-processes, and just need to figure out what PID belongs to your specific connection. If you connect via TCP, you could match your local connection port and map that against lsof to find the specific thread. Other ways are possible w/ strace, systemtap and more, or running an initial query you can watch for.

After that, you can use `ionice`/`renice` to affect the PID on the system. You will really want to make sure you capture what PID it was, and reset the nice & priority level afterwards, to not affect anything else.

As with the others, you really need to reshape this table in the long term. Partitions are useful, but not the endgame, since you're running 1.3TiB of online data, and you state that you only need to read from the most recent 3-6 partitions. Coming from MySQL before native partitions were added, I think this would be a good case for a VIEW and separate tables (atomically update the VIEW when you need to rollover). It would also let you trivially move some older tables to offline storage.

Comment: Interesting solution! Unfortunately this kind of 'messes' up our internal reporting system, because disk utilization  is permanently at 100%. Also, I noticed strange things happening in other places, but that might be caused by other processes having strange priorities.

Comment: Disk utilization of 100% is a CORRECT output for the situation.

Ideally you'd `ionice` the `ALTER TABLE` process  to use idle class, and leave your normal workloads alone, but the ALTER could take a very very long time if your system is busy. If you wanted to set very specific disk bandwidth limits (eg 10MB/sec or some number of IOPS), you could use the blkio cgroup system, and cgclassify or similar to move the process into the cgroup with your target limits.

Comment: We have cgroups planned for future changes (at the moment they're not used _at all_), it's rather difficult for me to 'just add this', but I do think this is a great idea!